# React Native - Cannot Space Evenly As Desired Within React-Native-Elements List Item

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

Below is my component and I just want space out the content in `<Text></Text>` evenly. The commented out code works as desired but the same is not working inside the list item for react-native-elements. Any tips?
Thanks.

```
import React from 'react';
import  { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';

const MemberList = ({members}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      {
        members && members.map((item, i) => (
          <ListItem key={i} bottomDivider>
            <ListItem.Content>
                <View style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                  <Text>{item.tag}</Text>
                  <Text>{item.country}</Text>
                </View>
            </ListItem.Content>
          </ListItem>
        // <View style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
        //   <Text>{item.t[![enter image description here][1]][1]ag}</Text>
        //   <Text>{item.country}</Text>
        // </View>
        ))
      }
   </View>
  )
}

export default MemberList;
```

Comment: Change `display: flex` to `flex:1`. There's no such thing as `display: flex` in react-native.

Comment: oh ok, I did not know that but still I had tried that earlier and tried it one more time no and when I do that all text disappears.

Comment: Also, just to note [ListItem.Content](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/listitem#listitemcontent) **is a view** - the extra view is superfluous. Just put the style prop right on `ListItem.Content`

Comment: got it, so I had added that after a bit of troubleshooting. Now I removed it and also removed display: flex and added flex:1. This seems to be working. So guess my problem initially was not having flex: 1 and when I added it, still did now work because of the extra View. Anyways this is working now. If you provide an answer above with this fix, I will accept. 
Thanks for your help.